# XFA filled PDF convert to Static pdf

Tags: java, python, powershell, pdf, xfa

I have XFA pdf which is already filled ,how to convert this XFA pdf  to static pdf programmatically?
Datalogics,itext are to much costly. i tried with PDFTOOLBOX ,PDFtK but data getting loss.
Print with save option are working but need programmatic solution .
Please help ...

Comment: Xfa in pdf is a technology that is not completely openly specified. Furthermore, xfa in pdf has been deprecated since 2017. Thus, why should anyone be interested in reverse engineering the missing parts and creating a library for that unless he is paid for that? So i won't be surprised if you don't find what you search.

Comment: Can you explain exactly which commands were you running on your XFA pdf using pdftk?

Comment: @Kuldeep pdftk in.pdf output out.pdf  flatten  , this command working my pdf getting flat but losing some data.

Comment: Can you check this https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-drop-xfa with flatten? I am not sure this is what you need, but have a look.

Comment: @Kuldeep i already tried that option same issue ,PDF get flatten but some form fields values loss.

Comment: If possible can you share the pdf? I am not able to find an XFA form to test.